# Como obtener el token de keycloak?

Tags: nodejs, api, keycloak

estoy haciendo un bot con nestjs, y tengo que hacerle consultas a un API que está protegida con keycloak. Yo tengo la URL, realm y clientId de keycloak pero necesito el token para pasárselo en el header de la consulta. Hasta ahora solo he visto este ejemplo

```
const keycloak = Keycloak({
  url: keyCloakConfig.url,
  realm: keyCloakConfig.realm,
  clientId: keyCloakConfig.clientId
});
    keycloak.init({
        onLoad: 'login-required',
        promiseType: 'native'
    }).then(auth => {
        if(auth) {
        console.log("token", keycloak.token);
        }
    });
```

Pero no funciona.
Si alguien me pudiera ayudar como hacerlo en nestjs o nodejs o decirme si el código de arriba tiene algo mal. Muchas gracias